# CSS3 Column Count Attribute

Tags: html, css

I am playing with the column count attribute in CSS3 and am running into an issue. I want two columns, each with a header. Instead I am getting two columns but the header of the second is at the bottom of the first.

This kind of layout is easily possible by floating divs next to each other, but, I would really like to get this column layout using the column attributes in CSS3.

Here is my code:

```
.wrapper {
    -webkit-column-count:2;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fpJeX/

Comment: To accomplish your goal, it would definitely work better to use floats. Columns aren't meant to do what you're doing, instead they're meant to work like newspaper columns, so once the content becomes to long for the first column, it continues on the top of the second column. If you had more content in the first `div`, you'd see that the content overflows into the next column, both the header and the text. [Check out this jsFiddle for an illustration](http://jsfiddle.net/fpJeX/2/).

Comment: Why do you need `column-count` if you can achieve that without it? [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fpJeX/3/)

Comment: Try adding some [height](http://jsfiddle.net/fpJeX/4/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is how a column-count is used. Anyway, you can check this out ...http://liveweave.com/v7YOXg